# Why are reaction rates proportional to the the product of the reactants not their sum?

Tags: stochastic-processes

For example, if we have the following Birth-Death process

[image: Birth-Death reaction]

Why is the differential equation describing this reaction given by

[image: Equation describing reaction]

Where x, y, and a are the number of the reactants (X, Y, and A respectively). The rate is always proportional to the product of the number of reactants, but why not their sum?

Comment: What should the rate be if the amount of one reactant is zero? Would it be that if the rate were proportional to the sum?

Comment: I see your point, because we want the rate to be zero if one of them is zero. It makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where x, y, and a are the number of the reactants (X, Y, and A
> respectively). The rate is always proportional to the product of the
> number of reactants, but why not their sum?concentration (or even better chemical acti

'number of the reactants' is an ambiguous term: *concentration* (or even better *chemical activity*) is more accurate.

If we take a simple reaction:

$$\text{A}+\text{B}\to \text{C}$$

Then in accordance with kinetic theory the rate of reaction is proportional to:

$$\frac{\text{d}[C]}{\text{d}t}\propto [A]$$
and:
$$\frac{\text{d}[C]}{\text{d}t}\propto [B]$$

It follows that:
$$\frac{\text{d}[C]}{\text{d}t}\propto [A]\times [B]$$
And:
$$\frac{\text{d}[C]}{\text{d}t}=k [A][B]$$

Where the bracketed quantities are *concentrations*.